# How to hide a class on specific page using css

Tags: html, css

I would like to hide the bullet point class="det_price" on the page "sale" only. Can someone tell me how to do it using css.

Here is an example of the code:

```
<body id="sale">
...
<li class="det_price">
</li>
...
```

Comment: `#sale .det_price{display:none}` <- this is if you are giving to `<body>` that page's `id` as you put in your code. If not, you would have to use some backend logic or javascript XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this CSS rule:

```
#sale .det_price {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#sale .det_price{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide, use `visibility` property with `hidden` value. This will hide it.

**For Instance,**

```
#sale .det_price {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

to hide the bullet point you could try like this..

```
 <div id="sale">
  <ul>
    <li class="det_price">test</li>

  </ul>
  </div>
```

and CSS should be like this

```
#sale>ul>li.det_price{list-style-type:none; color:red;}
```

here is the working Demo

http://jsbin.com/miciyuqi/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers work above, but you have to decide whether you want the information that is being "hidden" to stay in the HTML or be completely removed from the DOM. Display: none; will completely remove it, where visibility: hidden; will just hide it from the view of the visitor, but will keep the code in the DOM. There is a big difference between the two.